# xcode print folded regions as folded

Tags: xcode, printing, xcode4.3

Is there a way in xcode to print it so that items that are folded in the editor print as folded? I basically want a summary of methods in the file. It's actually javascript and not objective-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older XCode versions the answer is this:

Go into "print..." then choose **Show Details**. Under the Xcode option "Printing" there is a checkbox called **Expand folds**.

[image: Expand Folds]

For XCode 10 the print option `expand folds` has been removed.

Comment: This has been removed in XCode 10.2.1. How can I do it now?